# ngx formly (modelChange) | disable change notification for two fields

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

today I use the `(modelChange)` function, to know when there was a change in the model, however there are two fields that I need to disable detection, that is, when some data is inserted or changed in these two fields, it cannot reach until `(modelChange)`.

Lib: https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly

**Edit 1**: Stackblitz example, where when I change the value of the fieldExample field, I cannot trigger the modelChange function. In the documentation I found nothing.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-material-9nwfmk-j2rcbh?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: consider providing https://stackblitz.com/ live version of what you have problem on, lead you to an answer faster.

Comment: This question is hard to understand.

Comment: I put an example of stackblitz, in edit 1